# Pandas timeseries specifying time unit

Tags: time, pandas

I have an uneven timestamped data that I would like to process in Pandas. The timestamps are in milliseconds starting at 0, So the data looks like

```
Timestamp        Property
0                   1
1                   2           
2                   3
4                   4
10                  4
19                  7
```

I have a very basic question, I can create a pd.Series object with index as the Timestamp. But how does Pandas know that my timestamps are in millis or for that matter in secs or hours?

Comment: How can you read above data as Series with index as the Timestamp?

Comment: Sorry I am new to Pandas but I meant creating a pandas Dataframe and just setting the first column as the index? Does that not work? I guess where I am stuck is that how to tell Pandas that time is measures in millis?

Comment: You can specify the unit with eg `pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], unit='ms')`, but what is your base date? Because 10 ms is not a Timestamp, but maybe a timedelta?

Comment: Yes it is a delta, the base datetime is when time = 0, the expreiment starts when time = 0, which is the base.

Comment: You can have a column with `timedelta64` type, which can hold such data and for which you can set the unit (ms in your case), but pandas does not support this as index. So if you want it as an index, I would just keep it as ints, and make sure you remember yourself which unit it is.

Comment: No but how will I do pandas operations, say I want to shift the series by say 10 seconds? That becomes impossible? Related question is how to store milliseconds since epoch in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas assumes timestamps are in nanos, if you want to convert a column in millis, use `df['col'] = df['col'].astype('datetime64[ms]')`. Note that the final column will be in nanos.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how do you mean the final column will be in nanos? Once you convert it will in millis right?

Comment: Pandas uses `datetime64[ns]` internally for all dates always. You can get the millis back, as `int64`'s, with `df['date_col'].astype('int64') // 10**6`.